# No of solutions for this equation

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on a problem that requires the no of solutions for the below equation.

$x_1+x_2+2x_3+2x_4+3x_5+3x_6+4x_7+4x_8 = 20$

with $x_i\ge0$
Is it possible to use generating function to arrive at the number of ways to arrange this?

Comment: yes, generating functions are possible. however, due to the mass of terms, it is VERY impractical in this problem

Comment: Even in a sophisticated software like wolfram?

Comment: if you can use wolfram, go ahead

Comment: just truncate each parentheses to $x^{20}$

Comment: Let me try it , I have not until now.

Comment: that's going to involve a LOT of typing

Comment: Is there not another trick for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Mathematica, with

> Coefficient[Product[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, 20, m}]^2 , {m, 4}], x^20]

I get 6685 solutions.
Detailing them by contributions of the 4 twins by

> Coefficient[
>     Product[Sum[Subscript[a, m]^k x^k, {k, 0, 20, m}]^2 , {m, 4}], 
>     x^20] // Expand

produces 108 terms.

Comment: +1 for including the syntax. makes your answer MUCH more helpful :) does similar syntax apply to wolfram alpha?

Comment: I just checked on wolfram alpha : sadly, no. So much for the friendly user interface :-((

Comment: i guess it's more for elementary problems

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this is practical, but the generating function method would involve looking for the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3..)(1+x+x^2+x^3...)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6...)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6...)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9...)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9...)(1+x^4+x^8...)(1+x^4+x^8...)$

Comment: each one is geometric series and would reduce the typing.  Is it not?